# Pass data from Child to other Child with React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-hooks

So this is the Parent Function which passes the data to its children:

```
function Parent() {

  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");


  return (
    <div className="Parent">
      <BrowserRouter>

          <Route exact path="/child1" render={ () =>
             <Child1 setUsername={setUsername} setPassword={setPassword} password={password} username={username}/> 
             />

          <Route exact path="/child2" 
            render={() =>
             <Child2 username={username} password={password}/>
            }/>

        </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Parent;
```

What i try to achieve is, that **Child1** will get the data from an endpoint and it will store the data with `setPassword()` and `setUsername()` and the first Child redirects the page to the second Child (aka **Child2**).

The problem is that **Child2** won't get the data somehow and actually when i `console.log("Username: "+username)` or `console.log("Password: "+password)` i get `[object Object]`.

**Child1**:

```
export default function Child1({setPassword,setUsername,username,password}) {

  const history = useHistory();

  const handleClick = () => {
   setUsername("myUsername");
   setPassword("myPassword");
   history.push("/child2") 
  }

  return (
    <div>
      Child 1 Page
    <button onClick={handleClick}> A button</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Child2:**

```
const Child2 = (username,password) => {


    useEffect(() => {
         console.log("Username: "+username);
         console.log("Password: "+password);
    }, [])

    return (
        <div >
           Child 2 Page
        </div>
    )
}

export default Child2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget `{` `}`

**Explanation**

You will get props from the parent in the `props` object in

```
const Child2 = (props) => {...}
```

and you can access it any parent props with `props.*` and you can also use the destructuring method

```
const Child2 = ({username,password}) => {...}
```

Comment: i cannot believe that...... it was that simple, yet my eye didn't catch it and i thought i was doing something wrong. Thanks again and thanks for the explanation as well!
Im going to accept the answer in a min :)

Answer (score 1):

that's because you're trying to `console.log` an `object` as `string` , when you use `'a string' + someKindOfObject` the `javascript` will try to find a `toString()` function in `someKindOfObject` and if it couldn't find it it just outputs as `[object object]`.

So you need to change your code to something like this:

```
// use proper destructuring
const Child2 = ({username,password}) => {


    useEffect(() => {
         console.log("Username: ", username);
         console.log("Password: ", password);
        // remove useEffect dependency so you can see the data in every render - maybe the first time is just undefined
    })

    return (
        <div >
           Child 2 Page
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: thanks also for the answer. Shah answered first but thanks both of you. I can't believe i didn't see that.